# Using Wagon and connection error running tables query

Tags: mysql

I am using Wagon as my sql editor and I can'y access one tables. for some reason I'm getting

> problem running tables query: ConnectError "ConnectTimeout 10s"

I have no connection errors from what I can see.

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the command line?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.